# Jquery function for "read more" product category description is not working as expected

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

There's a link for my project http://inubia-projekt.dkonto.pl/product-category/sukienki/sukienki-wieczorowe/

What I want to achieve is when you click on "Czytaj więcej" the text will swap for "Zwiń opis". I also want attach function on the second span click ("Zwiń opis") that will make text short again. I am new to jquery and javascript so I need help with that. The code that I made is working only for expanding the text in one way.

Here's a code:

HTML:

```
<div id="read-more"><span>Czytaj więcej</span><span>Zwiń opis</span></div>
```

CSS:

```
#read-more span:last-child {
    display: none;
}

.visible {
    display: block !important;
}

.not-visible {
    display: none !important;
}

.visible-desc {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}

.term-description {
    max-height: 65px;
    overflow: hidden;
   margin-bottom: 20px
}
```

jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
   $(function() {
  $("#read-more span:first-child").click(function() {
    $(".term-description").addClass('visible-desc');
    $("#read-more span:first-child").addClass('not-visible');
    $("#read-more span:last-child").addClass('visible');
  });
});
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just make a few changes in your Jquery, instead of using addClass/removeClass use toggleClass :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
   $(function() {
      $("#read-more").click(function() {
          $(".term-description").toggleClass('visible-desc');
          $("#read-more span:first-child").toggleClass('not-visible');
          $("#read-more span:last-child").toggleClass('visible');
      });
   });
});
```